# How to set up DI / IoC and/or Factory pattern design in C#

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I have a design that requires an SSH connection in order to get to a command-line interface to run some system/feature level test automation.  There are several different types of SSH clients possible:

- Direct connections to a normal C/Bash shell
- Tunneled/forwarded connections within a VM or through a gateway server, etc.
- Connections that require a particular command-line debug interface to be launched from a shell after log-in
- etc.

I'm using the SSH.NET open source library as a NuGet package under C# with Visual Studio, and have gotten everything working in a simple case of connecting, issuing a command and reading back the StdOut and StdErr responses.

My issue is, I'd like to implement a few Session/Command layers here, and am not sure how to properly use interfaces to implement them.  I'd like to use DI/IoC to separate the `SshSession` and `SshCommand` layers from each other and from the SSH.NET `SshClient` class, but how do I get started with the design?

I've read a lot of explanations of DI/IoC and implemented some unit tests using IoC containers and such, but the core way to setup the DI is still not clicking.  I would think I wouldn't need an IoC container to implement this, but might need to use the factory pattern or even some other patterns I'm still not familiar with.

---

For example, to create multiple client types, with different connection criteria, I was thinking I would need something like:

- `ISshSession` interface
- `SshSessionBase : ISshSession` as a base class
- Then create custom classes that use `SshSessionBase` for each of the clients.

But then how does the DI actually work?  Do the custom classes get injected into the constructor of the base class, as `IsshSession` objects?  Or do I need another factory or executor class that consumes these custom class objects?

I might be mixing up topics here..  There's just something I'm missing to convert what I'm reading about into an actual implementation - appreciate any help!

Comment: It feels like I'm mixed up the base class design - maybe I don't need a base class (i.e. `SshSessionBase`) - or maybe I shouldn't inherit the interface - it should only be injected in the constructor?

Comment: When dealing with IoC you want to have a CompositionRoot where you setup a DI-Container to compose your application

Comment: @SirRufo Maybe, or maybe not - but I'm more asking how to correctly setup the classes in the first place to accept any objects that would be created by such a process.

Comment: I recommend reading the book [Dependency Injection in .NET](https://www.manning.com/books/dependency-injection-in-dot-net) if you want a solid understanding of DI, to understand where DI ends and the application begins, and when to use the appropriate design pattern instead of a DI container. There is really a lot more to your question than can be answered in Q & A format.

Comment: @NightOwl888 That's fair enough - I've seen other references to the book, looks like it's time to read it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not really sure if I understood your design, but the general approach could be the following:

1. Think about the behavioural and structural elements all client connection handlers have in common and either extract a base class or interface. For example, there might be a `Connect()` or `Send(ICommand)` method.
2. Think about the structural and behavioural elements of other components in your design, e.g. commands or loggers or whatever. Some sort of base class library will be the result.
3. Decide how you want to instantiate concrete instances of connection types. If the decission about the connection type relies on a set of parameters, you can utilize a factory. The factory will take a set of parameters and return a connection type instance. The factory could fulfill an interface itself and thus be resolved by the IoC itself (Abstract Factory).

The factory itself could just instantiate concrete classes, but your connection classes may utilize constructor-based injection to get access to other components (loggers, helpers, whatever), thus your factory could rely on the IoC Container, something like:

**Update**: As Michael pointed out, passing the container to the factory might be convenient but hides the concrete dependencies the factory has. While it might be okay with smaller applications, a better approach is passing all connection-type dependencies to the Factory which instantiates concrete instances.

```
class StandardConnectionFactory : IConnectionFactory
{
    private readonly IContainer iocContainer;

    public StandardConnectionFactory(IContainer iocContainer) 
    {
        this.iocContainer = iocContainer;
    }

    public IConnection Create(string param1, int param2, ...)
    {
         if (...) return iocContainer.Resolve<IFancySshConnection>();
         else return iocContainer.Resolve<IAnotherConnection>();
    }
}
```

4. If the decission about which connection type to use rather relies on some simple enum or string (e.g. the user decides what connection to use by a command line param), some IoC Containers (e.g. Autofac) allow to register a class with a name and resolve by that name. In that case, you do not need a factory and might end up with something like:

(Pseudo-Code)

```
// Registration Process
containerBuilder.Register<FancySshConnection>().For<IConnection>().WithName("ssh");
containerBuilder.Register<FancyFtpConnection>().For<IConnection>().WitName("ftp");

// Resolve
var connection = container.ResolveByName("ftp")
```

5. When you finished to implement a way to instantiate connections, either by an explicit factory (3) or some built-in instantiation (4), the dependencies of the connection type known to your IoC container will be injected automatically. For example, the above call to `iocContainer.Resolve<IFancySshConnection>();` will instantiate the concrete connection type, look at its constructor, try to resolve each parameter, inject them, and so on. It will climb up the dependency tree as long as it finds dependencies that were registered before.
   So basically all you have to do is registering your base class components (2).
6. If things get bigger and more complex, you may end up with alof of registrations. Some IoC containers (I stick to the Autofac example because I really like Autofac) provide an easy way to split registrations into modules. This allows to distribute the process of registration into different assemblies.

Comment: Not judging, but do you really think passing `IoC` container to factory is a good idea here ? You're implementing `Service Locator` which some (many?) think [is an anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern). So in order for me to be able to use your factory, I should know exactly what components have to be registered with IoC. Would you agree that it is breaking encapsulation ?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Cleaner would be injecting all needed  connection type dependencies into the abstract factory and instantiate concrete instances. I will update my answer. Thank you.

Comment: @mbnx Thanks - this is very helpful. So I need some method of building an IoC container, which could be manually, (likely) using a factory, or using an IoC container framework which allows registration.  I guess my question still is - what do I then do with the container - or what receives the container?  Is that the `FancySshConnection` class itself?  So I would create the container, use that to instantiate the particular connection class needed, and then operate on that object to connect, run commands, etc.?

Comment: Really depends on the application design. Somewhere you have to call something like container.Resolve(), from there on the IoC container will recursively inject dependencies into constructors. Try to minimize the number of classes that deal with the container directly. There is one initial class that handles container registrations. In the best case, only this class even knows about the container. In a console app, it could be the class with the Main method.

Comment: Okay, so a pure library would be looking for an outside application to construct the container, or something like unit test classes to do that, and a full-stack application would likely construct the container as a part of a UI or presentation layer?  Looks like time to try some things out.  :)

Comment: I think a library should not bother the consumer with a certain IoC framework, unless it is designed for a very special purpose. Either hide the IoC within the library or, as you suggest, provide all dependencies "unwired" and let the consumer wire things up with whatever IoC container he or she likes.